# Sharepoint Workflow Basics - Using Conditional Logic

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013.

In my workflow I am trying to make a condition dependent on the result of a custom task (check yes or no). How can I do this.

I am trying to use an if value = value condition but thing aren't working out. Please suggest a tutorial on how to use this condition. I think the syntax is the main issue. I understand programming logic.

```
Step: Step 1
If title field contains ________ _______
    Email name@??????

Step: Step 2
Collect Review Problem for _______ _______ from ?????????(Output to Variable: _______ ________ __)
Set Variable: ________ ________ status to _______ _______ Tasks:Problem Severity
If Variable: _______ _______ status equals Yes
    Email name@??????
```

The second step doesn't work

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't about suggesting tutorials, it's about answering questions about coding. Why don't you post the code you've tried and explain in which way it's not working? Then you're likely to get help in actually solving the problem.

Comment: O.K Adi I added the code. The second step doesn't work.